# How to check whether a byte of 8 bits contains 1, assembler 8051?

Tags: assembly, 8051

I need to know how to check whether a byte contains a 1 for touch status in a MPR121 project, so if:

> 00000010 then pin 2 is touched
>   00000100 then pin 3 is touched

How can I detect it?
A set bit means that a pin is touched. It does'nt matter whether there are more bits set, I just want to know if there is any bit set, because that means that a pin is touched not caring which is that particular pin.

I tried
R1-byte container

```
CJNE R1,#0, hasone
hasone:
   ....
```

But I don’t know if this works since it is comparing a hex with a number, I can do it comparing with every single solution, but I don’t like the approach.

Comment: what value do you have if none of the bits are set?

Comment: Do you need to know *which* bit is `1` or just that any is `1`?

Comment: What result do you want in case more than one of the bits is `1`?

Comment: Also, you might want to review the JZ and JNZ instructions.

Comment: This risks being closed as unclear what you are asking.  If the register has any bits set to one the value the register will contain anything other than 0x00.  If you want to know if bit zero is set then if ((R0 & 0x01) != 0) it is, for bit 2 if ((R0 & 0x02) != 0) it is, for bit 3  if ((R0 & 0x04) != 0) etc.

Comment: Are the only possible values 'b00000001, 'b00000010, etc., or can any combination of pins be activated at once?  What bitwise logical operator could you apply to an 8-bit register to make the whole thing non-zero if one of the bits is a 1 that would make it zero if the target bit is 0?

Comment: It can’t be combinations of 1s just 0001 0010 0101 ..., the 1 shows  that one particular pin is touched the zeros are not touched. I dont want to know wich one of the bits is set, just if any of them is set

Comment: @ÇlirimMurati, then you're back to looking at the JZ or JNZ instruction.

Answer (score 3):

If the byte is NOT 00000000, then at least one bit is non-zero. All you need to know is it is 00000000 or not.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all those if statements, you could use an 8 bit lookup table.  The code will execute much faster than performing all the if-then-else statements.  For the values you've indicated, 0x01, 0x02, etc the table below returns the number of the button pressed.  But there are a lot of 0xUU in the table.  0xUU means that the value has not been defined by you yet, as the comments have indicated.  You must decide what you want to return for those values and then update your lookup table.  You might set them to 0xFF, for example, if you wanted to detect an error.

```
 char lookup[] = {
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0xUU, 0x03, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0x04, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0x05, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0x06, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0x07, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0x08, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU,
    0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU, 0xUU
 }
 char result = lookup[R1];
```

Comment: I mentioned it has to be assembler 8051

Comment: This isn't really a free consulting service, you might have to do some work yourself.